# pgfplots: Using a column header as the plot title

Tags: pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use first row of a table as legend entry in pgfplot graph ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/use-first-row-of-a-table-as-legend-entry-in-pgfplot-graph)

I am creating a number of very similar plots using `pgfplots`. The raw data for these is provided in a single `.csv` file, so something like

```
x,a,b,c,d,e
0,0.04,0.03,0.04,0.03,0.04
1,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.05,0.06
2,0.06,0.07,0.06,0.07,0.06
3,0.09,0.08,0.09,0.08,0.09
4,0.13,0.12,0.13,0.12,0.13
5,0.13,0.12,0.13,0.12,0.13
```

(In the real case, there are a lot more rows and columns.) Each plot is separate (*i.e.* not on the same axes), but they are produced 'semi-automatically' using a suitable macro containing a plot environment of the form

```
\newcommand{\buildplot}[1]%
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
        [
          axis x line = bottom,
          axis y line = left,
        ]
        \addplot [mark = none]
          table [col sep = comma, y index = #1] 
          {example.csv};
       \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

The plots need to be differentiated, and the easiest way is to use the column header (in the example data `a`, `b`, *etc.*) as the `title` key. However, I cannot find a way to recover the header within the plotting environment to achieve this. As the information is already in the `.csv`, I would rather avoid retyping it in the document if at all possible.

Comment: Note that in the real case there is quite a bit more to the `\buildplot` macro, as there are various other settings which have to be adjusted on a plot-by-plot basis, plus some general set up to make things look good.

Comment: Not really an answer, but the `datatool` package (Nicola Talbot) uses provides an API for creating `tabular`s from CSV input. It seems to be capable of extracting the information in the first line/as well as ignoring it.

Comment: Perhaps the accepted answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/input-only-part-of-a-file) could be adapted. I recently did something similar to the requirements of this question using it without changes, saving the extracted text in a macro.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen The {input} tag seems to adhere to the answer you provided, not to the question, and so I removed it. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/whats-the-policy-on-retagging-questions-based-on-answers.

Comment: You can use the approach described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23993/use-first-row-of-a-table-as-legend-entry-in-pgfplot-graph to extract entries from a table/file.

Comment: @lockstep I didn't add the tag because my solution used input but because I felt that the general solution required dealing with input. Even if `pgfplots` has a solution for Jospephs problem, it'd be nice to know how to deal with the ``input''.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: If you think that the general solution requires dealing with the `\input` *command*, then you should add the [tag:input] tag again.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I've removed the [tag:input] tag here. As lockstep has said, it is not appropriate here (the question has nothing to do with `\input`).

Comment: @joseph It has to do with dealing with ``data input''.  Perhaps we should change the tag description/add a new tag?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I'm afraid I disagree: there is no issue with the data input, it's about _accessing_ the data using the mechanisms provided by `pgfplots`. If you want to pursue this, I suggest popping into the chat system. (Comments are not the best way to run a discussion.)

Comment: @joseph Yes but in a broader contex a solution without `pgfplots` would be desirable and would help similar questions in context with different packages. That's my point. No need to reply to this. I'll pose a question in a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a partial solution that shows how you may approach it. The disadvantage is that it uses `write18`. The example uses `head -1` to extract the first line from the `.csv` file and then another program to process the output, save it to a file and include the file. For the purpose of the example I use `sed` to change the delimiters. It's up to you to change this to whatever you want.

```
\immediate\write18{head -1 data.csv | sed -e 's/,/ delim /g' > file.tex}
\input{file.tex}
```