# Automatic labelling of isolines based on table's column name

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I would like my code to use the column name (from `pgfplotstable`) to automatically label the lines.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}    

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
T   1e5 2e5 3e5 4e5
100 1   1.5 2   2.5
200 2   2.5 3   3.5
300 3   3.5 4   4.5
400 4   4.5 5   5.5
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}{\DATA}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ylabel={T},
    xlabel={Values}]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i in {1,2,...,4} {
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\i}\of{\DATA}\to{\colname}
        \addplot+ table [x index=\i, y={T}] {\DATA} node [pos = 0.85, sloped, fill = white] {P = \colname};
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Here the indicated pressure is always the same, but I would like to take it from the column name of the table.

Same result with

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,2,...,4} {
    \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{#1}\of{\DATA}\to{\colname}
    \addplot+ table [x index=#1, y={T}] {\DATA} node [pos = 0.85, sloped, fill = white] {P = \colname};
}
```

Comment: You may want to look at the answer by Luigi at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79150/pgfplotstable-how-to-access-column-name

Comment: I updated my code with element found following your link, but strangely only the latest column name is used.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding (please correct me if I am wrong), all plot commands are evaluated in `\end{axis}`. Therefore, the value of `\colname` is the value of the last column (`4e5` in this case). In order to get the correct value, it must be evaluated in each loop. Follow the discussion in the `pgfplots manual, section 8.1` about the command `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`, I use `\edef` to get `\colname` evaluated. Note the use of `\noexpand` right before `\addplot` and `\DATA`. `\edef` will removes these `\noexpand` to give the following sequences of characters `\addplot` and `\DATA`. Since there is not a `\noexpand` right before `\colname`, it will be evaluated by `\edef`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}    

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
T   1e5 2e5 3e5 4e5
100 1   1.5 2   2.5
200 2   2.5 3   3.5
300 3   3.5 4   4.5
400 4   4.5 5   5.5
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ylabel={T},
    xlabel={Values}]
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}{\DATA}
\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\DATA}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
   \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberofcols}{
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{#1}\of{\DATA}to{\colname}
        \edef\letsdraw{\noexpand\addplot table [x index=#1, y={T}]
        {\noexpand\DATA} node [pos = 0.85, sloped, fill = white]
        {P=\colname};}
        \letsdraw
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```