# How to modify elements of this bar chart?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am currently producing the following chart:

[image]

With this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}  


\usepackage{color} % colors
\usepackage{xcolor} % more control over colors
\newcommand{\titlecolour}{blue!70!white}

% chart 1 data
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]%  % <--- 
{
    country,          3Q19,   4Q19
    US,             2.0,    1.9
    Euro,           1.2,    1.1
    PR China,       6.1,    6.0
    Singapore,      0.2,    0.1
    Indonesia,      5.1,    5.0
    Malaysia,       4.7,    4.4
    Korea,          2.1,    2.0
    Taiwan,         1.7,    2.9
    Philippines,    5.6,    5.9
}\chartone

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[ ##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},
    },
}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
\begin{axis}[
x=9mm,          
ybar,
x = 0.85cm,
bar width = 2mm,       
axis lines=left,
enlarge x limits=0.1,           
enlarge y limits={.2, upper}, 
% 
% y and x axis ticks
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1,
    /tikz/.cd, font=\scriptsize},
ymin = 0,
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate = 90},
symbolic x coords={US, Euro, PR China, Singapore, 
    Indonesia, Malaysia, Korea, Taiwan, Philippines},
%
% legends and labels
legend style={draw=none, legend columns=-1, at={(0.8, 1)},anchor=north east,                                      % 
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1em}},  % <---
y label style={at={(0.15,1)},rotate=-90,anchor=south},  % I prefer label along y axes
nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1,
    /tikz/.cd, font=\scriptsize, color = black},
legend style={legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Annual change (\%)},
]
\addplot[\titlecolour, fill = \titlecolour]
table [y=3Q19]  \chartone;    % <---
\addplot[yellow!80!black, fill = yellow!80!black, nodes near coords]
table [y=4Q19]  \chartone;    % <---
\legend{~3Q19, ~4Q19}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to make two adjustments:

1. Raise the `nodes near coords` slightly, so they aren't so close to the bars.
2. Set the values of the legend labels (3Q19 and 4Q19) as well as the x axis labels directly from the `chartone` table. Currently, they're being set manually, with the `\legend` and `symbolic x coords` commands, which is not ideal as it leaves room for human error.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 of your 3 points can be done quite easily. That is, add `yshift=...` to the `nodes near coords style` to shift the nodes and replace the `symbolic coords` with `xticklabels from table` and `table/x expr=\coordindex`.

You **can** get legend entries from table headers, but this only makes sense if you don't do something special to each and every `\addplot` command and therefore you could loop through the table columns (using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` or the like). As an example have a look at my answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355920/95441).

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
        /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
            /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
                \draw[ ##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
                (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},
        },
    }
    \colorlet{titlecolour}{blue!70!white}       % <-- (adjusted)
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
        country,        3Q19,   4Q19
        US,             2.0,    1.9
        Euro,           1.2,    1.1
        PR China,       6.1,    6.0
        Singapore,      0.2,    0.1
        Indonesia,      5.1,    5.0
        Malaysia,       4.7,    4.4
        Korea,          2.1,    2.0
        Taiwan,         1.7,    2.9
        Philippines,    5.6,    5.9
    }\chartone
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \small
    \begin{axis}[
        x=9mm,
        ybar,
        x=0.85cm,
        bar width=2mm,
        axis lines=left,
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        enlarge y limits={.2, upper},
        %
        % y and x axis ticks
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=1,
            /tikz/.cd,
            font=\scriptsize,
        },
        ymin=0,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels from table={\chartone}{country},    % <-- added
        table/x expr=\coordindex,                       % <-- added
        x tick label style={rotate=90},
        %
        % legends and labels
        legend style={
            draw=none,
            legend columns=-1,
            at={(0.8, 1)},
            anchor=north east,
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={
                column sep=1em,
            },
        },
        y label style={
            at={(0.15,1)},
            rotate=-90,
            anchor=south,
        },
        nodes near coords style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                fixed,
                fixed zerofill,
                precision=1,
            /tikz/.cd,
            font=\scriptsize,
            color=black,
            yshift=1ex,             % <-- added
        },
        ylabel={Annual change (\%)},
    ]

        \addplot [
            titlecolour,
            fill=titlecolour,
        ] table [y=3Q19]  {\chartone};
            \addlegendentry{3Q19};

        \addplot [
            yellow!80!black,
            fill=yellow!80!black,
            nodes near coords,
        ] table [y=4Q19]  {\chartone};
            \addlegendentry{4Q19};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Brilliant; I learned a lot from this!

Comment: You are welcome. That's what we -- the helpers -- are good for. Especially if they try to *understand* the answer to do it better the next time instead of just copy-pasting them without saying "thank you" (by upvoting and/or accepting an answer) which results in a "No thank you for just doing the job for me so I don't have to do it.".

Answer (score 2):

To long for comment ...

Some off-topic remarks (since your main problem is solved by nice @Stefan Pinnow  [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532039/how-to-modify-elements-of-this-bar-chart/532056#532056): +1) I wonder, why you in your MWE:

- define version of used `pgfplots` twice, first `compat=1.8`, than `compat=1.11` (at legend's style definition in preamble)
- define style of the diagram legend twice, ones in preamble, onse in the axis' optios
- why y-axis label is put on the top of diagram. There is usual place for diagram title, for clarity people put axis label along axis
- also I son't see any advantage to write y-ticks as 2,0, 4.0, ..., to my opinion it is sufficient 2, 4, ...

Considering aforementioned, The MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\colorlet{titlecolour}{blue!70!white}    

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
    country,        3Q19,   4Q19
    US,             2.0,    1.9
    Euro,           1.2,    1.1
    PR China,       6.1,    6.0
    Singapore,      0.2,    0.1
    Indonesia,      5.1,    5.0
    Malaysia,       4.7,    4.4
    Korea,          2.1,    2.0
    Taiwan,         1.7,    2.9
    Philippines,    5.6,    5.9
            }\chartone
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[x=12mm,
    ybar,
    bar width=4.4mm,
    axis lines=left,
    enlarge x limits=0.1,
    enlarge y limits={.2, upper},
% y ticks style and label
ylabel={Annual change (\%)},
    ymin=0,
% x axis ticks and style
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\chartone}{country},    % <-------------------
    table/x expr = \coordindex,                     % <-------------------
    x tick label style = {rotate=90},
% legends and labels
    legend style = {draw=none,
                    legend columns=-1,
                    at={(0.5,1)},
                    anchor=north,
                    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2em}
                    },
% nodes near coordinates
    nodes near coords style = { /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1,
                                /tikz/.cd, font=\scriptsize, color=black,
                                yshift=0.5ex,
                                },
    ]
\addplot [fill=titlecolour]
            table [y=3Q19]  {\chartone};
            \addlegendentry{3Q19};
\addplot [fill=yellow!80!black,
          nodes near coords]                        % <-------------------
            table [y=4Q19]  {\chartone};
            \addlegendentry{4Q19};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the further suggestions; I am learning a lot from how you write up the code too.