# Graph from csv table (col sep=comma) with pgfplotsinvokeforeach

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, csv

I have many huge csv files and need a easy way to plot all of them without defining headers etc. every time.

Therefore I found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24023/95657

That is exactly what I need but it doesn't work for csv files with comma separation.

The data isn't shown correct.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}       
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
        ,Distance,Velocity,Something
        0,0,1,0.2
        1,1,1,0.3
        1.5,1.999,1,0.4
        2,2,0,0.4
        3,2,0,0.5
    \end{filecontents}


    \newcommand{\plotfile}[1]{
        \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{#1}{\table}
        \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{#1}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberofcols}{
            \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
            \addplot table [col sep=comma, y index=##1] {#1}; 
            \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
        }
    } 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=north west]
        \plotfile{testdata.dat}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**What do I need to do to get this to work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What caused the error is, that you *also* missed to add `col sep=comma` to the `\pgfplotsread` command. (Besides that, I further "optimized" the code a bit.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
        ,Distance,Velocity,Something
        0,0,1,0.2
        1,1,1,0.3
        1.5,1.999,1,0.4
        2,2,0,0.4
        3,2,0,0.5
    \end{filecontents}
    \newcommand{\plotfile}[1]{
        \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{#1}{\table}
        \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\table}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\numberofcols}{
            \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
            \addplot table [y index=##1] {\table};
            \addlegendentryexpanded{\colname}
        }
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \plotfile{testdata.dat}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Nice! That works

Comment: You are welcome. If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Sure, I would have done anyway (just have to wait 5 minutes after asking to accept an answer).

Comment: *g, ok, learned something new today :)